# Why python .exe doesn't run on some PCs and others it does (Using pyinstaller)

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, pyinstaller

I'm working with selenium for automated tests, and I already did some upgrade to this script, like:

Setting up chromedriver.exe with `--add-binary` to .exe file, so once it starts executable creates temporary folder with chromedriver.

```py
path = os.getenv('username')


def resource_path(relative_path):
    try:
        base_path = sys._MEIPASS
    except Exception:
        base_path = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    return os.path.join(base_path, relative_path)


options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\{}\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data".format(path)) #Path to your chrome profile
driver = webdriver.Chrome(resource_path(".\\driver\\chromedriver.exe"),options=options)
```

Then I realized that my .exe was been
detected as a virus, found an solution for it, setting up bootloader for Pyinstaller.

And now I don't know why this .exe on some PCs it works with no problem, and in others it does nothing, no error is showed, also running it with terminal.

#### Important

When I compile and build the same script on the PC that my .exe doesn't run, the .exe built on that PC works perfectly.

Both OS are Windows 10 64bit;
The bootloader is set to win10 32bit and working on win10 64bit.

Python 3.9.0

Answer (score 0):

> When I compile and build the same script on the PC that my .exe
> doesn't run, the .exe built on that PC works perfectly.

That should tell you **something** is different between your two environments. It's a little strange you don't get any kind of error output.

From the [pyInstaller docs](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operating-mode.html#what-pyinstaller-does-and-how-it-does-it):

> The output of PyInstaller is specific to the active operating system
> and the active version of Python. This means that to prepare a
> distribution for:
>
> - a different OS
> - a different version of Python
> - a 32-bit or 64-bit OS
>
> you
> run PyInstaller on that OS, under that version of Python. The Python
> interpreter that executes PyInstaller is part of the bundle, and it is
> specific to the OS and the word size.

So check the OS matches (especially 32-bit vs. 64-bit), and also the python version(??)

Comment: Both OS is Win10 64bit, both with python 3.9.0 installed by scoop, may need I to set python enviroment to "C:\" instead user path?

Comment: Just take a look in pyinstaller website and found an update for 4.1 which has the following change log description:

Add support for Python 3.9
I will update it and try again.