# Irreproducible crash/behaviour of pyinstaller executable on different PCs

Tags: python, windows, pyqt5, crash, pyinstaller

I'm writing a little Python (3.11.3) program using PyQt5 and a few more modules.
Then I was packing this with pyInstaller (5.10.1) into an single file executable for Windows10.

On my laptop, I did not experience any problems, neither with the Python script nor with the executable.
However, when I copied the .exe to 3 other PCs and started it, I got 3 times some strange behaviour:

1. on PC 1 the .exe was crashing (I couldn't see what the error message was)
2. on PC 2 some table cells where suddenly empty after some table action
3. on PC 3 it crashed (error was something like `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '3-5`, however, this case should be excluded by the script)

Now, here comes the next strange thing:
This happened only when starting the .exe on the other PCs for the **first** time.
After restarting, this crashes/errors did not occur even with the same input.

Here on StackOverflow, there have been similar questions, but as far as I can judge no duplicates:

[Why python .exe doesn't run on some PCs and others it does (Using pyinstaller)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64896400/7295599)
No conclusive answer there. In my case, the PCs are all Windows10/64 systems.

[PyQt5 app compiled with PyInstaller using --onefile and --noconsole, but exe fails to launch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67418982/7295599)
In my case, the .exe started the second time, no pyInstaller `hiddenimports=[]` issues.

Some information about the used modules:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QAbstractItemView, QAction, QApplication, QHBoxLayout, QLabel, QLineEdit, QMainWindow,  QMessageBox, QPushButton, QTableWidget, QTableWidgetItem, QVBoxLayout, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot, Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
import sys, re, os
from pypdf import PdfReader, PdfWriter, Transformation
from math import cos, sin, atan, sqrt, radians, pi
```

Since the initial .exe was about 50 MB which to my opinion seems pretty large (but this is [another unsolved topic](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77009377/7295599)), I tried to reduce the size by using some excludes in the pyInstaller .spec file.

```
excludes=['pandas', 'numpy', 'matplotlib', 'scipy', 'PIL', 'sqlite3', 'setuptools', 'opencv', 'ocr', 'paramiko'],
```

With this, the .exe size was reduced to abut 40 MB. And again, with no crash or functional issues on my original PC.

Hence, unfortunately, I **cannot** give a minimal, reproducible example (maybe except posting the whole project).
I know this will make it probably difficult to give some advice.
However, maybe someone has experienced similar issues and can explain or give some hints what might going wrong here?

My suspicion was that on the different PCs there might be different versions of the "Microsoft Visual C++ redistributable". I could check that back if necessary. If any additional information might be necessary, I'll be happy to provide it.

Comment: With Occam's razor in mind I think the most likely cause is that there are bugs in your code.

Comment: @Alexander well, it could be that there might be bugs in the script, but why do they show up only on other PCs and only the first time? Some initialization issue of something?

Comment: Are you trying to distribute your application with a single file? Have you tried to export it with a folder (without the --onefile option)? I had problems with one files because of the antivirus (microsoft defender) as it blocked or deleted the executable whenever I attempted to run it, but that's all it happened to me so far. I never experienced crashes, after all I never used that flag anymore. Maybe it helps taking that flag out.

Comment: @CarlHR thank you for your comment. Yes, I used `--onefile` option since I very much prefer a single .exe file. However, I'll give it a try and let you know. Yeah, well, once, one of my programs (little helpers for various "harmless" purposes) has been identified by MS as dangerous and I got a mail from Global-IT department =:-O